# How can you set the duration of Laravel Nova Action Response Messages

Tags: php, laravel, toast, laravel-nova

According to [the documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-responses) we have the possibility to return toast messages when actions are being run. The success message of these can be shown using this kind of code:

```
return Action::message('It worked!');
return Action::danger('Something went wrong!');
```

The problem is that these messages are on screen for only a few seconds.

I am currently working on an action which takes 5-8 minutes to execute so if the user clicks away there's no way to keep that toast message on screen so that it's there when you open tab to resume work? Maybe with an "Ok!" button on the toast?

Answer (score 0):

send notification using the laravel nova 4 notification feature.

```
use Laravel\Nova\Notifications\NovaNotification;

$request->user()->notify(
    NovaNotification::make()
        ->message('Your report is ready to download.')
        ->action('Download', 'https://example.com/report.pdf')
        ->icon('download')
        ->type('info')
);
```

Comment: didn't get the chance to upgrade to Nova4 yet. From your code it doesn't seem to set the timeout. Should I assume that it waits indefinitely for the user to click on the action link?